# Copy deep nested object but omitting specific key, where key is also an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

There are many many threads similar to this one, but this problem it has an extra difficulty that I could not find a solution so far

I have an object like this:

[image]

I would like to deep copy this object into a new one, but for every element inside 'trainings' array I'd like to NOT copy 'sessions' and 'user' entirely

Few threads mention Lodash method _.omit() but that does not work for nested objects. Another package Deepdash has the _.deepOmit() method but the problem with that is that it does not work for keys that are Arrays.

I also tried the following solution

```js
let filteredData = _.transform(data, function (filteredData, value, key) {
  filteredData[key] = _.isArray(value) && `sessions` in value ? _.omit(value, 'sessions') : value;
});
```

but also unsuccessful

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package provides the exact solution for this problem:

https://github.com/odynvolk/omit-deep-lodash

And this is the usage to achieve the solution to my problem:

```
let filteredData = omitDeep(data,"sessions", "user")
```

[image]